# img tag (inside nav) disturbs the positioning of all element after it (margin also become useless)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a navbar with css alone, the only problem i am facing is when i put an **img tag** inside the **nav tag**, all the label after the image tag get wrong positioned! you can see in the pictures below.

i want to know why exactly is this happening?

**when img tag is present** the labels are outside the nav
[image]

**when img tag is absent** the labels are inside the nav (as they should be)
[image]

**Q1.** what does the image do that disturbs positions of all the element after it?

**Q2.** when img tag is present i cannot set margin of labels nor the div1 but if i remove img tag, now the margin works. **why?**

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #262426;
    height: 60px;
}

#div1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 800px;
}

#div2 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 200px;
}

#logo {
    display: inline;
    height: 50px;
    width: 66px;
}

.navItem {
    display: inline-block;
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: -153px; /* this does not work when img tag is on */
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div id="div1">
        <img src="logo.png" id="logo" />
        <label class="navItem">Home</label>
        <label class="navItem">Products</label>
        <label class="navItem">About</label>
        <label class="navItem">Contact Us</label>
    </div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `display:inline-block` to `display:flex` in id div1. it will aline all content inside div1 into one line. Than remove `margin-top: -153px` from class navItem. After those now you can put `margin: 5px 5px 0px 5px;` (You will put your desire margin as you need), between those label and img. Do rest of css as you need.

Comment: wow that really solved the problem but still i want to know the theory behind why these items get displaced in the first place? what wrong inline-block do that flex doesn't? and why does the margin stops working?

Comment: I think this link will clear your all confusions
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-inline-flex-and-inline-block-in-css/